# Copying bat file (itself) to appdata

Tags: file, batch-file, exe

I'm trying to make the bat copy itself to appdata folder. I have tried this

**copy %0 "%appdata%\windows.bat" > nul**

But it doesn't copy itself. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@copy "%~f0" "%appdata%\windows.bat" > nul
```

Do you have spaces in the file name? If yes this will require your file name to be put in double quotes.

Have you used the **CD** or **PUSHD** command? If yes you'll need to use full path instead of relative (with `%~f`).

have you used **SHIFT** command somewhere in the script? This can change the **%0** value.

Comment: Its named file.bat. Just have @echo off at the beginning and exit at the end. Tried both and doesn't work either.

Comment: @user198989 try to call it from the console or put `pause` at the end to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Added pause, it says "press any key to continue . . " when I do, it closes. There is no error. Possible to try on your pc ? Maybe the problem is on my OS

Comment: @user198989 - I've tried it on my pc (rarely I've post untested scripts here...) and it works.If there are no errors the file is copied somewhere.Add `echo %appdata%` to see the actual directory.